# How to implement related searches with elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine

Is it possible to implement "people who searched for this, also searched for" feature with elasticsearch? Just like what we often see in the search result at the bottom of Google search. If possible, how can we achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is this elasticsearch+Mahout based plugin available for implementing your solution. It may help you

https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-taste.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think " Item Recommender " feature of this plugin is likely to be what I want. In my situation, we have to calculate similar search terms from user input keywords. But I wonder how this plugin determine similarity between two items?( In my situation, this is two search terms) Furthermore, does this plugin support Chinese?

Comment: Thanks. I think I will try carrot plugin [link](https://github.com/carrot2/elasticsearch-carrot2/tree/master) for elastisearch to group similar terms

Comment: I think I will try carrot plugin[link] (https://github.com/carrot2/elasticsearch-carrot2/tree/master) for elasticsearch to group similar term based on search result.

Comment: I do not think it will support Chinese language. Well I have never tried that with anything other than English. That's good you got the plugin which is useful for your problem statement